# How to make a file opened in C++ thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, file-io, thread-safety

Code snippet:

```
ofstream log;
log.open("log.txt",ios::out);
Thread threads[2];
...both threads write to the file
log.close()
```

Any existing facility to lock the file when one thread writes to the file, so the two threads do not write at the same time. Thanks.

Comment: Use a logging framework, it will handle this for you. If you _really_ want to do it yourself, Mutex/Lock is what you are looking for.

Comment: you can use lock, semaphore, critical section on shared data(file-log) etc...

Comment: It's common to simply avoid this issue by queueing off writes to one 'logWriter' thread on a producer-consumer queue. Not only does it solve the title problem, it takes things like disk latency out of the log call, allowing the main app to run on without waiting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pwrite()`, it's safe write in multi threads.

Answer (score 0):

As what shang said,
`pwrite` Performs the same action as `write` but writes to the specified position in the file without modifying the file pointer and therefore is safe in threads.

See man pwrite(2) for more information.

```
 int fd = open('some_file',O_WRONLY);
 /* in threads */
 n = pwrite(fd, write_buffer, sizeof_buffer, file_offset);
```

In your case, you're probably going to have to lock before writing and keep track of the offset (where you are in the file) and then release the lock to ensure race conditions don't write over existing portions of the file and all actions to and from the file play well in concurrency land.